# Alpakka Kafka: Serialization exception with schema registry breaks the stream

Tags: apache-kafka, akka, alpakka

I am trying to figure out how to handle an exception with a faulty avro message. I am currently getting

```
{"@timestamp":"2019-06-13T20:20:38.636+00:00","@version":1,"message":"[Incoming aggregation] Upstream failed.","logger_name":"akka.stream.Materializer","thread_name":"system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition conversation-7 at offset 1737997. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing Avro message for id 42\nCaused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 51
```

As can be seen this breaks the stream. I am not able to handle this in the decider as it is part of the Consumer Source. 
In the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/errorhandling.html) it says that I should read the stream as raw bytes and do the parsing manually in a Flow stage further in the processing chain. However I don't think that it is possible if I'm using Schema registry.

Can someone give me a hint on what the proper way to handle this is?

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Alpakka Kafka are you using? The error is supposed to be propagated to the stream, and then a decider can be used to react on that error. This was improved in https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/pull/615 and the relevant closed ticket is https://github.com/akka/alpakka-kafka/issues/356

If you still find that supervision does not apply, could you create a ticket in the Alpakka Kafka issue tracker?

Comment: I am using the latest version 1.0.4. I have set a decider through the ActorMaterializer but that doesn't help.